# COPY FROM file to Cassandra iqnoring solr_query coumn

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax

i can't import data to cassandra because i am using DSE Solr now and as i can see it created solr_query (virtual column) in my table.

So i tried COPY table FROM 'file' WITH SKIPCOLS = "solr_query";
but getting same error.

Failed to import 10 rows: ParseError - Invalid row length 9 should be 10 -  given up without retries.

So how can i import data and ignore solr_query column ?

Answer (score 0):

The copy command accepts the columns to import as a list [COPY](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html%20%22%20COPY). Try to list them, avoiding the `solr_query` column, and it should be ok:

`COPY table (colA, colB, colC,...) FROM 'file'`